# Interior doors no longer fit flush with frames when closing

Tags: doors, carpentry, door-frame, hinges, jamb

I've had some hooks over the top of my bathroom, bedroom, and office doors for the past few months. I remember the doors fit fairly snugly to the frame when I closed them around the time I moved in (a few mm of space around the door's edges). Now, I think either the doorframes have warped or the doors themselves have started to droop under the additional weight, as the edge of the door now contacts the frame when closing. The doors then "stick" shut.

I've tried tightening the screws on the hinges that the doors are hanging on, but it's made no difference.

I'm considering two options:

1. I could plane away an inner part of the frame and repaint, but I live in a rental flat, so I don't want to do any major carpentry if I can avoid it.
2. I could take the doors off entirely and rehang them using longer screws.

Is there a more straight forward fix that I'm missing?

Comment: Is it the changing weather?  I wonder if humidity changes are causing it temporarily?

Answer (score 2):

One trick I've used is to remove a few screws on the top hinge and replace them with very long screws that can reach the stud (assuming wood studs).   That can (not always, but sometimes), snug up the jam to the stud, raise up the door just a bit and fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Can this be done one at a time with the door still hanging? The important thing is that the screw reaches the stud, right? My guess is that the studs are wood. This is a newly (but relatively cheaply) renovated flat.

Comment: Most doors use three or four screws per side.  One is usually enough to hold for a tiny bit of time.  Hinge screws usually short about 3/4 to an inch.  Would want a couple to be 2 to 3 inches.